# How to create UIView like IMDB app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view

I'm trying to recreate a view.
I've seen in the IMDB app and have no idea how to do the same thing.

I'm fairly new at app building, so any advice would help.

In the IMDB app when you select pics of an actor, you get a grid view of photos.

- If you tap one, it goes full screen.
- If you tap full screen pic, 2 semi-transparent bars appear at top and bottom overlapping photo.

These bars contain buttons and text.

How would I recreate this in my own app? Is it a special view? Modal views I know appear from bottom and fill whole screen.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You need to attempt something and as you run into trouble, post more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

This question is far too vague, you need to attempt this and post more specific questions as you run into problems, but here's some high-level insight to get you started: (Mind you, I haven't seen the IMDB app)

A grid view of photos could be done with a UITableView or a UICollectionView (either in a full size view controller, or placed into a UIPopoverController for iPad), and when someone taps on one you could launch a new view controller that consists of simply a UIImageView filling the screen (you could do this as a full-screen modal).  In any case, this view will need to have 2 views (with backgrounds set to alpha < 1.0) which will contain your buttons and text.  You will set those views to hidden until the user taps on the full screen image (which you can use a UITapGestureRecognizer for).

Take a whack at it yourself, and when you run into specific issues, post them here and the fine knowledgable people here at SO will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a modal view without having them come up from the bottom. `pushViewController:animated:`(if you're using a UINavigationController),`presentModalViewController:animated:`,`presentViewController: animated:completion:` all have a BOOL option to turn `animated` on or off. They probably just turned the animation off.

Comment: But in the IMDB app, the 2 semi-transparent bars at top and bottom both animate in from top and bottom. Can you guys check out the app and see, because it's hard to explain, and I really don't know if it is a custom made view or one that is tweaked. Thanks for the help. I'm away from computer for the day, so I can't try anything yet!

Comment: saw the app: it's something like this probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718539/custom-animation-when-hidding-uinavigationbar (i.e. using setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES with UIView animateWithDuration) with the bar being black translucent and the bottom view is just a custom uiview with animatewithduration